# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AidController (?). Please make sure that the argument AidService at index [0] is available in the AidModule

Tags: nestjs

This one has me stumped after I tried a few things such as exporting `AidService` from the AidModule and that did not work.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AidController } from './aid.controller';

@Module({
  controllers: [AidController],
})
export class AidModule {}
```

I don't think it's asking me to import `AidService` into `AidModule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AidService` does not exist in the context of the module so you have to add it as a provider and your controller would be able to resolve it.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AidController } from './aid.controller';

@Module({
  controllers: [AidController],
  providers: [AirService]
})
export class AidModule {}
```